# Is there any legal protection for actions that later become illegal?

Tags: united-states

For example, lets say that being a software developer is a legal occupation right now. But 2 years from now, it becomes illegal to develop software.

- Can you be prosecuted for work that you've done in the past that has only recently become illegal?
- Are there any legal protections / immunity currently in place to prevent this type of situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is known as a *retroactive* or *ex post facto* law. Such laws are explicitly forbidden by the US Constitution ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_post_facto_law) reference), and are generally frowned on in jurisdictions where the rule of law applies, partly because it is difficult to prove criminal intent when your action was not at the time criminal.

Comment: Obviously any retroactive law could be deeply unfair, but I think in the UK what counts is the intent to do what you did, and not the intent to commit a crime.

Comment: An intent to commit a crime means that you are aware that the act is a crime. I don't think there is any law in the US where one has to actually know that the act is criminal, hence ignorantia legis neminem excusat.

Comment: -1: many crimes do not even include an element of intent.  The more compelling argument against ex post facto laws is that it is manifestly unfair to prosecute someone for an act that was legal at the time of commission.

Comment: @phoog The simplest crime, theft, requires intent. HOWEVER it does require intent to take something away, not intent to commit a crime.

Comment: @gnasher729 as far as I can see that supports the view that intent is not a particularly important reason to forbid ex post facto laws.

Comment: @phoog: If an action is legal at some times and illegal at other times, someone who performs the action at a time when it is legal isn't breaking the law, even if they're fully aware that the action would be illegal if done later.  This is equally true if the action is one which is allowed and disallowed according to a schedule, or if the action is one which is allowed until a law is passed forbidding it.

Comment: @supercat what does that have to do with intent?

Comment: @phoog: By saying that criminal intent may be hard to prove if performs an action which isn't presently illegal, but will be in future, the answer implies that criminal intent could *exist* in such cases, and implies the obstacle to proving intent would be showing the person knew that the action would become illegal.  My point was that criminal intent doesn't exist even in cases where someone knows an action will be forbidden.

Comment: @supercat my point is that the intent element (in crimes where it exists, which is in any event is not all crimes) is not an intention to commit a crime.  It is an intention to do some specific act or to achieve some specific result.  To say that this prevents ex post facto laws is either begging the question, misunderstanding what "criminal intent" means, or both. It doesn't matter whether the person knows that the intentional act is criminal; it only matters that the act is intentional.

Comment: @phoog: For many kinds of malum prohibitum offenses, the state has a duty to notify people of what is and isn't legal.  If e.g. all parties stipulate that: 1. someone deliberately sold X on January 30; 2. the state had recently passed a law saying X would become legal on January 31, published a brochure saying X would become legal on January 21, and shortly thereafter published a notice saying it had sent out brochures giving an incorrect date, and specifying the correct date, the person's guilt or innocence could depend upon whether they were reasonably unaware of the printing error.

Comment: @phoog: My point was that unlike that kind of situation, where an action may be illegal without being prosecutable, an action which has not yet been forbidden *isn't even illegal* in any sense of the word, thus rendering the question of intent moot.  Perhaps a better example would be a situation where an emergency measure is passed forbidding something, effective immediately at 5:42pm on some date.  Issues of intent may be relevant if someone is charged with violating the measure at 6:00pm, but not if they were charged with violating it at 5:30pm.

Comment: @supercat "isn't even illegal in any sense of the word, thus rendering the question of intent moot": this is where you're misunderstanding the meaning of "intent."  For example, suppose a juridiction that permits ex post facto laws decides to outlaw jokes.  It structures the offense such that saying a given sequence of words is forbidden only if you intend to make someone else laugh.  The law passes in 2023, effective in 2022.  When you are prosecuted in 2023 for telling a joke in 2022, the prosecutor must prove that you intended to make someone laugh. That is the criminal intent, ...

Comment: @supercat ... even if it wasn't criminal at the time.  Examples of intent as an element of a crime include "with intent to cause physical injury to another person" and "intentionally accesses a computer without authorization."  In a world where ex post facto law was permitted, it would not matter whether causing physical injury to another person or accessing a computer without authorization were legal at the time of the act being prosecuted, it would only matter that these acts were done intentionally.

Comment: @phoog: The way in which the term "intent" is used *in the answer only* makes sense if it is intended to refer to an intention to disobey a law which was known to exist.  I know the term "intent" is usually used in other ways, but I can't see how any of them would be relevant to the answer above.  If the government passes a law that says X is illegal, effective immediately, and someone performs the act 2 seconds after the law is passed, intent *to disobey the law* would be relevant, but if the government passes a law that says something will be illegal effective 23:59:59, and...

Comment: ...someone performs the action a minute before that, then whether they knew about the upcoming prohibition or not, the action would even in retrospect be legal.

Comment: @supercat the goal of my comments is to point out that this answer is wrong to use "intent" that way because that's not how the criminal justice system uses "intent."  Intent to disobey the law is never relevant.